# How to get textbox name based on its value in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to get the hidden text box name.

```
  <input type="hidden" value="100" name="test1_season_1">
```

Here the value will always be 100 and name will be changing dynamically.

Can you help me on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there always be only one hidden input on your page? Also how will the name change? Is there some rule? For instance is test1_season_ fixed, and only the last number changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/53tKF/

This will fit your need, `:)`

Also note inside the demo I have created an anti case so that you can see it only alerts 2 times i.e. input `type=hidden` & `value=100`

**code**

```
$('input[type="hidden"][value="100"]').each(function(){

   alert($(this).prop('name')); 
});​
```

Comment: +1 Since this is the only answer that also checks for the hidden-type.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But the alert fires only when i replace "prop" with "attr".

Comment: The value which we got is a dropdown id, based on that id we have validate the dropdown. can i put that code here itself or do i need to put that as a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Simple option (not necessarily the best way to check value though):

```
$("input[value='100']:hidden").attr("name");
```

More complex (or at least more wordy):

```
$("input:hidden").filter(function() {
    return $(this).val() == '100';
}).attr("name");
```

Comment: Yo Bruv, I reckon check for the type as well and do a loop I reckon OP might have more then one text box `:)` rest looks saweet. +1 anyways `:)`

Comment: Thanks man, added the check for hidden type. I thought he was only doing this for one input field, but he can add a loop as needed.

Answer (score 0):

`$('input[value="100"]')` will give you the hidden field.